# Side effects on re enabling an IRQ line from within an interrupt handler

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

What kind of side effects might appear if an IRQ line is incorrectly re-enabled via spin_unlock_irq in a hard interrupt context? In other words, why is the spin_lock_irq()/spin_unlock_irq() pair discouraged there?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14963815/1755108

Comment: It does not really answer my question: what is the risk of re-enabling the irq line? What can happen?

Comment: I added an answer, hopefully it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because say, if the interrupts were OFF and then you acquire a `spin_lock_irq` and then `spin_unlock_irq`. This `spin_unlock_irq` will enable the interrupts back again. But you had started with the state of the system where interrupts were OFF and now they are ON. This is undesirable.

So, what you are doing using `spin_lock_irqsave` is to ***save/preserve** * the state of IRQ (ON or OFF) and when you do a `spin_lock_irqrestore`, you return to the IRQ state that was set before you acquired the lock.

From http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/5833:

> With a call to spin_unlock_irqrestore(), interrupts are restored to
>   the state when the lock was acquired.

**Risk:** 
When the interrupts are supposed to be disabled and you enable it and there is an IRQ handler that was running (with IRQ disabled) could lead to nesting of interrupts and too much of nesting can crash your system (for eg a network IRQ that interrupts thousands of times within a second).

---

**From the kernel source:**

**[spin_lock_irq](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/spinlock.h?v=2.6.34#L307)**

```
326 static inline void spin_lock_irq(spinlock_t *lock)
327 {
328         raw_spin_lock_irq(&lock->rlock);
329 }
```

**[spin_lock_irqsave](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/spinlock.h#L331)**

```
331 #define spin_lock_irqsave(lock, flags)                          \
332 do {                                                            \
333         raw_spin_lock_irqsave(spinlock_check(lock), flags);     \
334 } while (0)
```

Here you are first checking the state of `IRQ` and preserving it.

```
290 static inline raw_spinlock_t *spinlock_check(spinlock_t *lock)
291 {
292         return &lock->rlock;
293 }
```

And similar source you can find for `spin_unlock_irq` & `spin_unlock_irqrestore`