# Can an interrupt handler be preempted?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, interrupt

I know that linux does nested interrupts where one interrupt can "preempt" another interrupt, but what about with other tasks.

I am just trying to understand how linux handles interrupts. Can they be preempted by some other user task/kernel task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: An interrupt can only be interrupted by interrupts of higher priority.

Therefore an interrupt can be interrupted by the kernel or a user task *if* the interrupt's priority is lower than the kernel scheduler interrupt priority or user task interrupt priority.

Note that by "user task" I mean *user-defined interrupt*.

Comment: Very late on this but there is no notion of interrupt priority in vanila linux kernel.

Answer (score 11):

Reading [Why kernel code/thread executing in interrupt context cannot sleep?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1053572/119790) which links to Robert Loves [article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6916), I read this :

> some interrupt handlers (known in
>   Linux as fast interrupt handlers) run
>   with all interrupts on the local
>   processor disabled. This is done to
>   ensure that the interrupt handler runs
>   without interruption, as quickly as
>   possible. More so, all interrupt
>   handlers run with their current
>   interrupt line disabled on all
>   processors. This ensures that two
>   interrupt handlers for the same
>   interrupt line do not run
>   concurrently. It also prevents device
>   driver writers from having to handle
>   recursive interrupts, which complicate
>   programming.

So AFIK all IRQ's are disabled while within the interrupt handler, therefore it cannot be interrupted!?

Comment: All irqs are not disabled by default only the same irq is disabled on all processors. but with flags in request_irq, you can disable all other interrupts on local processor while serving the interrupt.

Comment: @Jagdish Since 2.6.35 / 2010 all IRQs _are_ disabled on the local core: see https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/e58aa3d2d0cc01ad8d6f7f640a0670433f794922 and https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/b738a50a202639614c98b5763b01bf9201779e50