# Calling schedule() inside Linux IRQ

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, user-mode-linux

I'm making an emulation driver that requires me to call `schedule()` in ATOMIC contexts in order to make the emulation part work. For now I have this hack that allows me to call `schedule()` inside ATOMIC (e.g. spinlock) context:

```
int p_count = current_thread_info()->preempt_count;

current_thread_info()->preempt_count = 0;
schedule();
current_thread_info()->preempt_count = p_count;
```

But that doesn't work inside IRQs, the system just stops afer calling `schedule()`.

Is there any way to hack the kernel in a way to allow me to do it? I'm using Linux kernel 4.2.1 with User Mode Linux

Answer (score 5):

In kernel code you can be either in **interrupt context** or in **process context**.
When you are in interrupt context, you cannot call any blocking function (e.g., `schedule()`) or access the `current` pointer. That's related to how the kernel is designed and there is no way for having such functionalities in interrupt context. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053572/why-kernel-code-thread-executing-in-interrupt-context-cannot-sleep).

Depending on what is your purpose, you can find some strategy that allows you to reach your goal. To me, it sounds strange that you have to call `schedule()` explicitly instead of relying on the natural kernel flow.

One possible approach follows (but, again, it depends on your specific goal). Form the IRQ you can schedule the work on a [**work queue**](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/workqueue.txt) through `schedule_work()`. The work queue, in fact, by design, executes kernel code in process context. From there, you are allowed to call blocking functions and access the current process data.