# Why interrupts require very fast servicing?

Tags: interrupt-handling

Is there another reason except for slowing the system a little bit?

I ask it because of nos's comment here:

[Why kernel code/thread executing in interrupt context cannot sleep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053572/why-kernel-code-thread-executing-in-interrupt-context-cannot-sleep)

> Also, interrupts usually require very fast servicing, or you can easily get into all sorts of trouble.

Which kind of troubles could be made?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever had that your computer was busy working, for instance during startup, and you kept pressing keys, and after a while you just got a beep and those keys weren't registered/buffered anymore? That's an example of what can happen.

If you don't handle the interrupt fast enough, the inflow may be larger than you can handle, and there is no room to queue more interrupts.

Modern hardware and modern OS'es will not run into such limits as quickly as Ye Olde DOS machine, but that doesn't mean that their buffers are unlimited.

Comment: There are another reasons besides full buffers? Any by the way, why and where there are interrupt queues? Aren't interrupts interruptible?

Comment: Well, another example is a network card. It buffers the data it receives, and triggers an interrupt after every so much data. If those interrupts are not handled in time, the network card needs to drop any extra data it receives. It shouldn't fire an interrupt for every received packet (would consume too much CPU), and it needs to buffer the data to allow receiving data while the previous data is still being processed, but obviously such a buffer is limited in size, so once fired, the interrupt should be handled as fast as possible.